# How can I use the app/bootstrap.php way to load Magento JS?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Known that we can run Magento 2 Code externally using include('app/bootstrap.php').
After loaded we can  freely to create $objectManager to load different model.

However is it possible to load the Magento javascript library/js widget?
For example, one of the payment integration is using js library to encrypt sensitive information and I want to run this logic in my externally code.

Can I run the js library which is implemented as a method renderer js?

[Adyen payment example](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-magento2/blob/6.0.0/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/adyen-cc-method.js#L300-L321)

Comment: which version are you using 2.3 , 2.4 ...?

Comment: I am using 2.3.5-p1